# SQL Table design for condition based values

Tags: database-design

I have a requirement to store the config information values based on the range of the values.

Here is the requirement: I am suppose to store the color code based on the field values.  For example, if field value is:

```
fieldValue > 0.5 then Red , 
fieldValue > 0.3 && fieldValue < 0.4 then Amber 
fieldValue < 0.3 then Green 
fieldValue < 0 then Blue
```

For now, I have thought of the below table design

```
create table conditional_config    
(    
 condition_id varchar2(50) primary key,    
 condidtion  varchar2(100),    
 color_value archer(20)     
);
```

Sample entries will look as below (contain_id, condition, value)

```
condition1, >0.5, RED 
condition2, >0.3 && 0.5<, AMBER 
condition3, >0 && <0.3, GREEN 
condition4, <0, BLUE
```

Suggest any better design option.

Comment: what are you doing to use condition for?

Comment: This condition is basically to derive color code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use that data to programmatically compute the color, I'd recommend breaking it up into two fields: LowerLimit and UpperLimit. Make these fields numeric and then you can use them directly without having to do a whole lot of parsing:

```
create table conditional_config    
(    
    condition_id varchar2(50) primary key,    
    lowerLimit float(3,2),    
    upperLimit float(3,2),
    color_value archer(20)     
);
```

For red, you can set upperLimit to 3.402823466E+38

For blue, you can set lowerLimit to -3.402823466E+38

Limits for floats taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Comment: Thanks Rubix, nice and simple solution.

Comment: I am also thinking to store the entire condition expression as a condition field. For example storing the condition as,
fieldvalue>=0.5?'RED':fieldvalue<0.5 && fieldvalue>0.3?'AMBER':fieldvalue>=0 && fieldvalue<=0.3 ?'GREEN':'BLUE'

Let's store this conditional expression and who ever want to find the color, then replace fieldvalue with actual value, then can get the color

Comment: If you want to do that, write a stored procedure that takes a value as input and outputs the color

Answer (score 1):

I would start out by changing the way the criteria is stated slightly:

```
fieldValue > 0.5 then Red
fieldValue > 0.3 then Amber
fieldValue > 0.0 then Green
fieldValue > -9999 then Blue
```

with the rule being "the applicable color value is the largest value less than or equal to the condition value.

```
Values:
Field Color
===== =====
0.5   Red
0.3   Amber
0.0   Green
-9999 Blue
```

This gives the following query:

```
select  c.ConditionValue, v.Color
from    Conditions c
join    Values     v
    on  v.Value =(
            select  Max( Value )
            from    Values
            where   Value <= c.ConditionValue );
```

Now, I've created an arbitrary lower limit and this could well work fine if you know the lowest bound your values may contain. If this is not known, you can change the lower boundary from -9999 to `NULL` or just remove that row altogether. Then the query would be:

```
select  c.ConditionValue, IfNull( v.Color, BLUE ) as Color
from    Conditions c
left join Values   v
    on  v.Value =(
            select  Max( Value )
            from    Values
            where   Value <= c.ConditionValue );
```

but then you would have to remove the Blue color from the table to your code, which is not the best form.

Comment: How do u plan to store the values in condition table ?

Comment: I have no idea how you get those values into the Condition table. My answer did not involve any changes to that table. So just assume no changes there.